# Are there any Islamic teachings on child education?

Tags: quran, hadith, education

Are there any teachings from the Quran, Sunna or from the sira (biography) of the Prophet (peace be upon him) and his successors (the 4 Khulafa') about child education?

If so, do this methods go ahead with modern child education teachings?

If not are their any other Islamic methods or advises on child education?

Answer (score 2):

One of the most important advises in Islam for raising children, said in modern terms : " Lead by example ". That is , do not ever lie to your child, in any way. He will pray if he sees you pray, he will be helpful to others if he sees YOU help the others. Telling him to do a behavior and doing its opposite is a sort of lying to him.

A second one is about the stages of the child life, and how to do with him :

1. in his first seven years, you play with him. That means you raise him by love in his early sevens. He is still young and needs love from you, so reveal to him your kindly face : play with him, bring him toys, learn him the good behavior by kind words and tender feelings.
2. In his second seven years, that from 7 to 14 : discipline him. Show more strict behavior, and this of course depends on the behavior of the child.
3. In his third sevens, that is fro 14 to 21 : treat him as a friend. He is now growing up, he needs to feel that he is treated as a grownup by you. This boosts his self confidence and prepares him to the grownups life to come.
4. After that : he is now an adult, so let him live his own life, armed by what you give him in the 3 stages before.

I hope this helped.
God bless you.

Refrences :

http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/219

Comment: Could you support your claims with references?

Comment: Yes , by Hadeeth Shareef, but it will be in Arabic.

Comment: That's fine. You can also post a link from http://sunnah.com/ as you may find the major sunna collections there.

Comment: (حديث مرفوع) ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عَامِرٍ ، قَالَ : جَاءَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ إِلَى بَيْتِنَا ، وَأَنَا صَبِيُّ صَغِيرٌ ، فَذَهَبْتُ لأَلْعَبَ ، فَقَالَتْ أُمِّي : يَا عَبْدَ اللَّهِ ، تَعَالَ أُعْطِكَ ، فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ : " مَا أَرَدْتِ أَنْ تُعْطِيَهُ ؟ " فَقَالَتْ : أَرَدْتُ أَنْ أُعْطِيَهُ تَمْرًا ، فَقَالَ : " أَمَا إِنْ لَوْ لَمْ تَفْعَلِي كُتِبَتْ عَلَيْكِ كِذْبَةٌ " .

Comment: Please add it to your answer here's a source from Sunan abi Dawod http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/219 I knew this hadith but thought it was 'aisha (May Allah be pleased with her) whom said come here ...

Comment: The link added  to the answer. If you want, you can promote the answer.

Comment: For the second point in the answer, it is either a hadeeth حديث ضعيف , or a techung from the Sahaba رضي الله عنهم .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38961/discussion-between-medi1saif-and-drwael).

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm usig the android app from my telephone, and i think the app do not have chat ability.

Comment: I see this is an auto message. Well the chat room is open for a few days and maybe we can talk later!

Comment: Any time :-) God bless you.